# rails rendering html from rack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rendering, rack, rackattack

I'm using rack attack. If somebody exceeds the limit I'm using the following code:

```
Rack::Attack.throttled_response = lambda do |env|
  [429, {}, [ActionView::Base.new.render(file: 'public/429.html')]]
end
```

When sby exceeds the limit on a POST request where the original response would be `respond_to :html` then the rendering of the `429.html` works fine. When the limit is exceeded by a POST request that responds to `respond_to :js` then nothing happens on the screen, but if I check out the logs everything seems to be fine:

```
Rendered public/429.html (1.4ms)
```

How can I display the `429.html` in case of `js response`? Is it possible to pass down `error messages` from this rack code to the rails app somehow? I may change to `error messages` from `rendering` if it's not that complex.

Answer (score 7):

```
Rack::Attack.throttled_response = lambda do |env|
  html = ActionView::Base.new.render(file: 'public/429.html')
  [503, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, [html]]
end
```

You can set any response content type in the second params.

Comment: For Rails 6, you will want to use `ActionView::Base.empty` instead of `ActionView::Base.new`